# Add or append new element to XML file in Scala instead of replacing it

Tags: xml, scala, scala-2.10, scala-xml

My scala code currently ends up replacing an entire section of my xml file with the new tag that I'm adding. I want it to only add the tag once as a child of ClientConfig but it replaces all the tags present in this section with itself.

```
val data = XML.load(file)
val p = new XMLPrettyPrinter(2)
val tryingtoAdd = addNewEntry(data,host,env)
p.write(tryingtoAdd)(System.out)
```

where host=bob and env=flat are previously defined and addNewEntry is defined as follows

```
 private def isCorrectLocation(parent: Elem, node: Elem, host: String): Boolean = {
    parent.label == "ClientConfig" && node.label == "host"
  }

  def addNewEntry(elem:Elem, host: String, env: String): Elem ={
    val toAdd = <host name={host} env={env} />
    def addNew(current: Elem): Elem = current.copy(
      child = current.child.map {
        case e: Elem if isCorrectLocation(current, e, host) ⇒ toAdd
        case e: Elem ⇒ addNew(e)
        case other ⇒ other
      }
    )
    addNew(elem)
  }
```

The xml it produces is

```
<ClientConfig>
    <host name="bob" env="flat"/>
    <host name="bob" env="flat"/>
    <host name="bob" env="flat"/>
    <host name="bob" env="flat"/>
</ClientConfig>
```

where instead I want it to just append it as a single child of ClientConfig such as this where the last three children were already present in the file

```
<ClientConfig>
    <host name="bob" env="flat"/>
    <host name="george" env="flat"/>
    <host name="alice" env="flat"/>
    <host name="bernice" env="flat"/>
</ClientConfig>
```

What do i do? For example python has a simple insert method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, when the pattern match goes to

```
case e: Elem if isCorrectLocation(current, e, host) => toAdd
```

The toAdd method will use the host, env you pass in `addNewEntry(data, host, env)`. bob for host, flat for env. So, toAdd will always return `<host name="bob" env="flat"/>`.

Assume you have the client.xml like this:

```
   <Root>
     <ServerConfig>
       <host name="allen" env="flat"/>
     </ServerConfig>
     <ClientConfig>
       <host name="george" env="flat"/>
       <host name="alice" env="flat"/>
       <host name="bernice" env="flat"/>
    </ClientConfig>
   </Root>
```

The following code is how I try to get it done.

```
    def toBeAddedEntry(name: String, env: String) = <host name={ name } env={ env } />
    def addNewEntry(originalXML: Elem, name: String, env: String) = {
      originalXML match {
         case e @ Elem(_, _, _, _, configs @ _*) => {
            val changedNodes = configs.map {
                case <ClientConfig>{ innerConfigs @ _* }</ClientConfig> => {
                    <ClientConfig> { toBeAddedEntry(name, env) ++ innerConfigs }</ClientConfig>
                }
                case other => other
             }
            e.copy(child = changedNodes)
         }
         case _ => originalXML
     }
   }   

    val originalXML = XML.load("client.xml")
    val printer = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80,5)
    println(printer.format(addNewEntry(originalXML, "bob", "flat")))


    // result
    <Root>
      <ServerConfig>
        <host env="flat" name="allen"/>
     </ServerConfig>
     <ClientConfig>
       <host name="bob" env="flat"/>
       <host env="flat" name="george"/>
       <host env="flat" name="alice"/>
       <host env="flat" name="bernice"/>
    </ClientConfig>
   </Root>
```

Besides, I notice one thing during the process. XML.load actually [reverses attribute order](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6341), maybe it's irrelevant for solving your problem but just adding it here in case you need it.

Comment: Where is the method toBeAddedEntry coming from? It seems to throw an error when I compile this

Comment: @Zee, sorry my fault,  just added it.

Comment: Fixed the last issue! One more question, what is configs supposed to be here?

Comment: @Zee, If you look at the definition of Elem,  you will know that configs with type Seq[Node] actually mean the Node between <ClientConfig></ClientConfig>, the simple way to test it is to print it out.

Comment: it seems to add the node outside of the clientconfig. When i specify a location to add such as (originalXML \\ "ClientConfig") it gives a type mismatch. How are you getting it to add inside of the ClientConfig tag

Comment: @Zee, hey , why are you doing this originalXML \\ "ClientConfig", I edited my answer. It seems that you are not clear about the structure of originalXML. I use pattern to extract the Seq[Node] of ClientConfig and then make some modifications.

Comment: The issue is that it seems to arbitrarily add it above and outside the ClientConfig area of the xml file. Are you just using the entire file in your XML load method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85016/discussion-between-allen-and-zee).

Comment: Sorry for that, yes, I just load  the entire file in XML load. So, what am i missing , please tell me.

Comment: There is xml before the ClientConfig tag and when I use your code, it ends up adding it outside of the ClientConfig tag so for example it adds it 
<xml>
<host env="flat"  name="bob">
<Client Config>
<host env="flat" name="george"/>
   <host env="flat" name="alice"/>
 <host env="flat" name="bernice"/>

</ClientConfig>

Comment: So you mean in the file I am gonna load, the structure is actually like <ServerConfig><host name="george" env="flat"/></ServerConfig>
<ClientConfig><host name="george" env="flat"/><host name="alice" env="flat"/><host name="bernice" env="flat"/></ClientConfig>, and you wanna add <host name="bob" env="flat"/> as the first child of <ClientConfig></ClientConfig>, am I right?

Comment: @Zee, hey, check the edited answer, hope this time I get it right.

Comment: @Zee, ha ha, thank god,  I am also kind of  worn out. Hey, I happen  to notice that you have asked a few questions about Scala XML, so I suggest you have a deep read of  Working with XML chapter in Programming In Scala, it may help a lot. Besides, you'd better offer more details about the question you are gonna ask next time to help others understand your problems better. In you case,  the structure of the xml file. you see we both waste a lot time on clarifying the real problem of question. Anyway, get it done.

Comment: I actually read the whole chapter on Scala XML from Odersky's book but I'm very new to scala and the examples in the book were very basic compared to this. Regardless, im still continuing to read it

Comment: Truly is, when I was a newbie, I started to read that book, also confused. Yes,  you should continue. After solving a series of Scala XML problems, I bet you will better understanding of that chapter. So, that's it, good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/geirolz/advxml

it's a simple library in order to simplify the XML transformation